# How to attach event to svg circle that calls a function

Tags: javascript, svg

I am creating some circles at runtime `(document.createElementNS('','circle'))`.
I need to attach a mouseover event that calls a function.

I've tried 
 `addEventListener`, `setAttribute` but it is not working:

```
  circle.setAttribute('onmouseover', this.showPopup);
  circle.addEventListener('onmouseover', this.showPopup);
```

Comment: **mouseover** not onmouseover

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener("mouseover"`  not `onmouseover`

eg.

```js
const svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const c = document.createElementNS(svgNS ,'circle');
c.setAttribute('cx', 50);
c.setAttribute('cy', 50);
c.setAttribute('r', 50);

svg.appendChild(c);

c.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
  console.log("mouseover");
});
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi Razva, Thanks for you answer. it is not working for me. I have   
    for (let i = 1; i <= point_counter; i++) {
     (....)
      const circle = document.createElementNS('....', 'circle');
      circle.setAttribute('pointer-events', 'visiblePoint');
      circle.setAttribute('cx','10');
      circle.setAttribute('cy', '10');
      circle.setAttribute('r', '10');
      g_marker.appendChild(circle);
       svg.appendChild(g_marker);
      circle.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        console.log('mouseover');
      });

    }

Comment: @user1671727  Who is Razva?..  Also run the snippet above it works fine.  Move your mouse over the circle and it will console log mouseover.

Comment: Sorry Keith, wrong name. Yes, I did test the example but in my code is not working.

Comment: @user1671727 `document.createElementNS('','circle')` that is wrong too, look at my snippet to see how you create a svg circle in code.

Comment: Keith, I remove teh contain because there is restriction of chars.  what I have in the line is  const circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');

Comment: @user1671727  As the snippet above show it works, so something else is causing you problem in your code.  Do you get any errors in the console?  Or alternatively can you provide a snippet / fiddle that shows your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Keith for your help. Not I do not have errors. The only difference is that in your code you are getting the SVG object from the rendered page and in my case, I am creating the SVG on runtime. So it could be that because the SVG is not in render yet the event is losing after is render the page.